# sql- suppressing the amount value to get the unique value when its multiple rows of same information

Tags: sql, teradata

Sorry for the confused title.

I am on Teradata 16.1, I have two tables, one is a simple table with id and amount and another one is a detailed table with sub id's and their amounts. In the second table the amounts are splits of the sub id's which makes up the amount of id's.

When Joining these tables the table A amount is getting repeated (  which is obvious ), but I need to get it only once so that I can reconcile that amount to other tables.Thinking of two solutions ( and open to others as well) but dont know how to achieve in sql. Its all in the Image.

Any insights?

```
create volatile table  main_table
(
 id varchar(10), amount decimal(10,2) )  primary index (id) on commit preserve rows;




 insert into main_table values ('A1',600); insert into main_table values ('A2',700); insert into main_table values ('A3',800);




 create volatile  table sub_table
(
 id varchar(10),  sub_id varchar(10), sub_value decimal(10,2) ) 
 primary index (id,sub_id) on commit preserve rows;


 insert into sub_table values ('A1','X1',300); insert into sub_table values ('A1','X2',300); 
 insert into sub_table values ('A2','Y1',700); 
 insert into sub_table values ('A3','Z1',200);insert into sub_table values ('A3','Z2',300);insert into sub_table values ('A3','Z3',300);
```

[image]

Comment: Which table is the desired output? Is your goal to write a query for amounts validation (sum of sub_table values equals to main_table , per ID)?

Comment: How about a 3rd solution: *return the same amount as sub_value*. Assuming value and sum(sub_value) don't always match this can be done with a Cumulative Sum: e.g. for A3 200,300,300, loooks better than 266.6667 (and this will sum up to 2100.0001)

Comment: Dima G: The goal here is to get a single flat table with the sum of table1 amount is same as table2 amount.

Comment: dnoeth: Yeah I am open for solutions but am not sure whether the cumulative sum will be always the same as table 1. In this case it looks like its same.

Comment: You should know your data :-) If it's always the same then there's no need for calculation. Otherwise it depends on how to display the missmatched numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can number rows from sub_table to identify the 1st and hide main_table amount on others

```
WITH 
s as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by subid) n, *
    from sub_table 
)
select m.id main_id, case when n = 1 then m.value else 0 end main_value, s.id sub_id,  s.value
from main_table m
join s on m.id=s.id
```

result

```
main_id main_value  sub_id  value
A1  600 A1  300
A1  0   A1  300
A2  700 A2  700
A3  800 A3  200
A3  0   A3  300
A3  0   A3  300
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can just use `JOIN` and some additional logic:

```
select m.*, s.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by m.id order by s.subid) = 1
             then m.amount
             else 0
        end) as imputed_a_amount
from main_table m left join
     sub_table s
     on m.id = s.id;
```

Or:

```
select m.*, s.*,
       m.amount / count(*) over (partition by m_id) as imputed_a_amount
from main_table m left join
     sub_table s
     on m.id = s.id;
```